# Add multiple values to single array element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large array (~10^7 elements) that I want to map to another array, with fewer elements.

For example,

```
data = np.array([53.6, 47.9, 12.3, 2.45, ... , 8.35, 9.40]) # 10^7 elements
output_array = np.array([0.0, 0.0, ..., 0.0, 0.0)] # Say 10^5 elements, initialized to zero
```

I have an array of indices the same length as 'data' that maps each value to the new index in 'output_array'. There are many duplicates, and there may be indices in output_array that have no values mapped to them.

For example,

```
inds = np.array([1260, 1260, 1260, 1238, 1238, 2359, 234, ..., 2509, 120])
```

I want to be able to add all the values in 'data' to its corresponding index in 'output_array'.

```
output_array[inds] += data
```

does not work, because it only retains the last value mapped to each index.

Currently, my best solution is as follows:

```
inds_uniq = set(inds)
for ind in inds_uniq:
    output_map[ind] += np.sum(data[np.where(inds == ind)])
```

I am just wondering is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `output_array[inds] += data[inds]`?

Comment: No - `data` and `inds` are the same length.